# _.filter array of objects using a property with either value

Tags: lodash

I'd like to filter an array of objects I only want objects with status equals to 0 or 1 this is my code.

```
_.filter(array, { status: 1 || 0 });
```

but its not working it only fetches objects with status equals to 1.

```
_.filter(array, function (a) { return a.status === 1 || a.status === 0 });
```

Works but I'd like to know the shorthand method. How do I  accomplish this without using the function method?

Edit: 
Okay, got it. What I was actually looking for is arrow function.

```
_.filter(array, a => a.status === 1 || a status === 0);
```

Comment: updated my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

your shorthand is not valid, read more about [_.matches](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.2#matches) predicate, in your case use function

```
_.filter(array, item => _.includes([0, 1], item.status))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `function` as predicate:

```
_.filter(array, function(i) { return i.status === 1 || i.status === 0; }
```

https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.2#filter